# Как записать строки в foreach?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте помогите разобраться. Вот код:

```
function razdel() 
{
    $file = file("ancorrzd.txt");

foreach($file as $str_number => $str_content) 
{
    echo "строка " . ($str_number + 1) . " : " . $str_content;
}

$file = fopen ("rzd.txt","w");
$str = "$str_conten";
fputs ( $file, $str);
fclose ($file);
```

Выводит на экран строки из ancorrzd.txt. Предположим, что скрипт будет исполняться n раз. Нужно, чтобы при каждом запуске в rzd.txt записывалась все новая строка.
Вот [ссылка](http://narod.ru/disk/19111900001/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(3).rar.html) на весь скрипт.

Comment: Если не секрет, зачем исполнять скрипт несколько раз?

Comment: Вообще бессмысленный какой-то у вас скрипт. Лучше объясните на словах, что вы пытаетесь реализовать.

Comment: Есть файл со множеством строчек, каждая строка - имя для будущего файла, вот и все.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function razdel() 
 {
    if(file_exists("rzd.txt"))
        $file1_c = count(file("rzd.txt"));
    $file = file("ancorrzd.txt");
    $fp = fopen("rdz.txt","a+");
    fputs($fp,$file[$file1_c]);
    fclose($fp);
```

может так?

Comment: так то оно так, вот только в rzd.txt записались все строки сразу, а нужно только одну, а потом когда начнется следующая интерация в цикле нужно записать строку номер 2, потом 3 и т.д.

Comment: переписал

Comment: У вас ошибочка - rdz.txt, поправил м все заработало, СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: Ну, если заработало, то слева от ответа есть такая кнопка с галочкой).

Answer (score 1):

[fopen()](http://php.net/fopen)

> The `mode` parameter specifies the type of access you require to the stream. It may be any of the following:
>
> - `'a'` - Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the end of the file**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 1):

> есть файл со множеством строчек, каждая строка- имя для будущего файла вот и все.

```
function razdel() 
{
    $file = file("ancorrzd.txt"); // получаем названия файлов
    foreach($file as $name) // пробегаемся по ним циклом
    {
        $fp = fopen(trim($name), 'w'); // создаем файл
        fclose($fp); // и оставляем его в покое
    }
}
```

Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Теперь я вас не понял.

Comment: Дописал комменты.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но все равно ничего не получается.

Answer (score 0):

```
fputs($file,each(file('из какого файла')));
```

- как-то так.